# Can anyone tell me why I am getting the syntax error in the SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Why I am getting syntax error, can anyone tell me?

My table name is `customers`.
Getting syntax error when using `IS DISTINCT FROM`.

Here is the table

[image]

And here the error screenshot

[image]

Comment: Probably because mariadb does not support `is distinct from` operator. I never heard of such operator myself.

Comment: @Shadow Are you sure ?

Comment: @NinjaBoy : what makes you believe that you used correct syntax (IS DISTINCT FROM) ?

Comment: I am just learning to SQL and getting syntax error when using IS DISTINCT FROM. So i just want to clear my concept whether the operator is not supported in mariaDB or may be i am using the wrong syntax, but i am sure i am not using wrong syntax because i have searched over the internet about the syntax and finally got that this operator is not supported in mariaDB.

Comment: @NinjaBoy if you want to know if a product supports a certain feature or not, then pls do not ask, but check out the products manual first. It is really not that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to only get rows where start does not equal end and ids are DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM customers WHERE start!=end;
```

Comment: This assumes that `start` and `end` are `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

`is distinct from` is the ANSI standard way of including `NULL`, so `NULL` is different from another value. This is called a `NULL`-safe operator.

The `NULL`-safe operator in MySQL/MariaDB is `<=>`.  However, this is for equality, not inequality.

So, you want:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where not (c.start <=> c.end);
```

Comment: Just as described in the duplicate topic...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know mysql is unable to run the query.You can use below query instead,I hope it will helps you.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `customers`   
WHERE ((`start` <> `end` OR `start` IS NULL OR `end` IS NULL)
AND NOT (`start` IS NULL AND `end` IS NULL))
```

Comment: @Shadow says that IS DISTINCT FROM is not supported in mariaDB, is that true ?

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
select distinct *from table1 where start <> end_
```

example with output shown as below

[image]